# How to Write a program in Servlet Program to Present data in Pdf form..?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

1. This is a simple java class which is using iText jar to create a pdf file but the problem is while running the java class it creates a pdf file in the project folder. But how to call that java class to create the pdf file from Servlet.
2. How to present data in pdf using Servlet.

"If it is possible please give me a reference from where i can learn all these thing to create pdf using servlet or Java class.

Comment: I am not getting clear requirement, provide snap code. You can write PDF creation code in a method of class and call that method from a Servlet. If you want PDF creation then you can use Jasper Report (iReport) tool which is developed in Java and it is easy. You can design report as per your requirement. And then you have to just call that report from Servlet. Then the PDF file will be created at given location or you can load directly in browser also.

Comment: Actually, I am using itext for creating a pdf file but I want to create a pdf format for user to present data and every time i write code it simply reply a message "failed to load". So basically i want how to write a code to present data in pdf format.

Comment: Could you please provide any best reference from where I can learn how to present data in pdf form by using servlet...

Comment: Hi Dj_learner, very soon I am going to upload Jasper Report videos of mine. Or you can search on youtube for 'Jasper Report Tutorials'. You will get an ideas.

Comment: Thanks @SachinParse